# How to allow Firefox webdriver access to microphone & camera?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I need Firefox to allow camera/mic usage with selenium webdriver in Python 3

Trying to figure out how to do this for Firefox:

```
    options.add_option("prefs", { \
      "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,           
      "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
        })
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `options.set_preference(...)` ? docs: [selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.set_preference(name, value)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options.set_preference)

Comment: thanks @davedwards that did it!